# authenticate_or_request_with_http_token always returning false with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, heroku, afnetworking

```
before_filter :restrict_access

def restrict_access
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
    true
  end
end
```

Here you can see that I'm returning true always for `authenticate_or_request_with_http_token`, just as an attempt to force it to work. However, I'm encountering an extremely strange issue.

I'm sending in an `Authorization` header with value `Token token=token value here`

The client here is an iOS app using AFNetworking.

When the iOS app calls this on localhost:3000, it works as expected, and I do not get a 401 error.

With the same exact code however, when I run this on a remote server (Heroku), I get a 401.

However, the 401 only occurs on the remote server when the client is an iOS app. When running this via Paw or Postman, it works just fine. It's mind boggling.

Here's the iOS code that sets the Authorization header:
`[self.operationManager.requestSerializer setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Token token=%@", accessToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];`

**Why would running a request from iOS Simulator -> localhost work just fine, but running the same request from iOS Simulator -> Heroku not work and result in a 401?**

And remember, `authenticate_or_request_with_http_token` is always returning true. So it seems to me that Heroku might be modifying the Authorization header format, so that it becomes an invalid format, and that block is never called. `authenticate_or_request_with_http_token` seems to return false by default if the Authorization header format is screwed up, like if I pass in `token=432` rather than `Token token=432`.

Comment: I am having the same issue . Whats the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what the issue was. According to [NSURLRequest docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableURLRequest/addValue:forHTTPHeaderField:):

> IMPORTANT
>
> The NSURLConnection class and NSURLSession classes are
> designed to handle various aspects of the HTTP protocol for you. As a
> result, you should not modify the following headers:
>
> Authorization
>
> Connection
>
> Host
>
> WWW-Authenticate

So the issue was that you're not supposed to modify the Authorization header. Behind the scenes, it appears that NSURLRequest was modifying the Authorization header after I had set it, and emptied it out so it wasn't delivered. Not sure why it would do this for Heroku and not localhost, but there you have it.